# Manipulating with large byte array input

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm working on a project where I'm getting a large (70k) array of bytes.

I have to decode it and parse the result properly, based on the data.

Array is built like this:

```
{ header_cells, dataType1, dataType1..., dataType2, dataType2...}
```

Is it the best solution to use here the ByteBuffer?I know all lengths, basically I wanted to split it using:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[SIZE];
byte[] output = buffer.get(arr, offset, length);
```

And the wrap it into my objects.

Is it a good solutioon, or is there something better?

Comment: on the margin: are You sure this should be used in Java as byte? Seems legal strngs. MANY string parsers exists

Answer (score 0):

70k `byte[]` array is roughly 68kb of memory, which is nothing on any modern hardware. Focus on the code being readable first and optimise only if the performance problems are spotted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deep copy memory each time you need an sub sequence, you can use buffer [slices](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice())

But, be aware that whole background array will be in memory unless your have at least one slice reference.

For example:

```
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
buff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
for(int i=0; i < 128; i++) {
    buff.put((byte)i);
}

// use custom code instead of flip, to provide a slice
buff.position( 32 );
buff.limit(64);

ByteBuffer subBuffer = buff.slice();

// custom flip
buff.limit(128);
buff.position(0);

System.out.print("Sub buffer: [");
for(int i=0; i < subBuffer.limit(); i++) {
    System.out.print( String.format(" %d,", subBuffer.get(i) ) );
}
System.out.println(" ]");

System.out.print("Whole buffer: [");
for(int i=0; i < buff.limit(); i++) {
    System.out.print( String.format(" %d,", buff.get(i) ) );
}
System.out.println(" ]");
```

Outputs:

```
Sub buffer: [ 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, ]
Whole buffer: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, ]
```